# CB_GETLBTEXT notification to a program

Tags: winapi, sendmessage

I'm trying to modify the selection of a particular combobox. I have already retrieved the handle successfully. However, when I call the function as below, I cannot modify the combobox selection properly:

```
r = SendMessage(cbox, CBN_SELCHANGE, 2, 0);
```

What would be the easiest method to accomplish what I want to do? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CBN_SELCHANGE is just a notification, it is sent via a WM_COMMAND message to the parent window when selection changes by the user.

CB_SETCURSEL is the message you need to use.

```
SendMessage(cbox, CB_SETCURSEL, 2, 0);
```

Should work.

Comment: Also note that you can use the macro `ComboBox_SetCurSel(cbox, index)` defined in `<windowsx.h>`.